# Grails withForm, reset token on error?

Tags: forms, authentication, grails, submit, grails-2.0

Currently using grails 2.2.2

I've been trying to implement tokens into my application and have come up with this issue. We try to avoid re-rendering pages because it can be very slow so we return JSON instead. The following is a basic controller call that we use but I'm not sure what I should be doing to reset/get a new token.

```
public saveThing(ThingCommand cmd) {
    Map model = [:]
    withForm {
        try {
            thingService.saveThing(cmd)
            model.success = true
        } catch (Exception e) {
            model.error = true //any validation errors or anything else
            // RESET TOKEN HERE/GET NEW TOKEN?
        }
    }.invalidToken {
        model.invalidToken = true
    }
    render model as JSON
}
```

From my understanding the token is thrown away once the withForm closure is executed. This causes an issue since I don't actually re-render the form which seems to be the normal way of generating a new token. How could I do this manually or is there an easier way to do this (plugin?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form tokens through `withForm` are not designed to be used with AJAX requests. They are designed to be used with HTML forms and POST requests which re-render the form and generate a new token for the form.

In order to make them work with JSON/AJAX requests you will need to implement your own token generation when you process the request and reject it. A good starting place would be to look at the [old tests](https://github.com/gramant/grails-core-old/blob/master/grails-test-suite-uber/src/test/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/metaclass/WithFormMethodTests.groovy) which test `withForm`. This should give you an idea on how tokens are created and stored.